# Yii2 updating two related models does not show data of the second

Tags: activerecord, yii2, active-form

I have two related models in hasToMany relation. The first is `Invoices` and the second is `InvoiceItems`. As a prototype process, I'm trying to conjugate the two models through the `update` view of the `InvoicesController` using the following code in `actionUpdate` of `InvoicesController`:

```
...
use common\models\Invoices;
use common\models\InvoicesSearch;
use common\models\InvoiceItems;
...

public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $invoiceItems = new InvoiceItems();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            $invoiceItems->invoice_id = $model->id;
            if ($invoiceItems->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $invoiceItems->save()){
              return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
            else{
              // return false;
            }
        } else {
          $invoiceItems->invoice_id = $model->id;
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
                'invoiceItems' => $invoiceItems,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

The following in `update` view:

```
<div class="invoices-update">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
        'invoiceItems' => $invoiceItems,
    ]) ?>
</div>
```

Finally, the following in `_form` view:

```
<div class="invoices-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'created')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'type')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
  <hr />
    <?= $form->field($invoiceItems, 'item_id')->textInput();?>
    <?= $form->field($invoiceItems, 'unit_id')->textInput();?>
    <?= $form->field($invoiceItems, 'qty')->textInput();?>    

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

The above code succeeded in saving data in `invoice_items` table. **However**, the update view form has empty fields for `InvoiceItems` model. i.e `item_id`, `unit_id` and `qty` are empty in the update form after saving.

**Notice:** This is initial code, i.e I will work later to be able to add many items to the invoice, but now I just try to have one item related to the invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the update view is empty because you render and empty  InvoceItmes ..

```
 $invoiceItems = new InvoiceItems();
```

you render update view in else section and this section the value posted are not loaded

```
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $invoiceItems = new InvoiceItems();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        $invoiceItems->invoice_id = $model->id;
        if ($invoiceItems->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $invoiceItems->save()){
          return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
        else{
          // return false;
        }
    } else {//****** here the $invoceItems is empty (It has just been created) ***
      //$invoiceItems->invoice_id = $model->id;
      $invoceItems= findInvoceItmesModel($model->id);
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'invoiceItems' => $invoiceItems,
        ]);
    }
```

for populate the data for $invoceItems you need somethings like

```
protected function findInvoiceItemsModel($id)
{
    if (($model = InvociceItems::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Obviously this is for a single model.. you must refactory form more than one..

Comment: Well! What could I have to do to fill it with data?

Comment: When I try to `$invoiceItems = $model->getInvoiceItems();` it returns an error: `Calling unknown method: common\models\InvoiceItemsQuery::formName()`

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you hint me if I need to found all items of an invoice. I tried to use `findAll` instead of `findOne` but it returns the error: `Call to a member function formName() on array`

Comment: FindAll is right but remember that the result is a collection of models and not a single model. then for accessing to each model you need or an iteration or an index..

Comment: Very useful, I would like to mention that loop should be occurred in the view i.e `_form`