# Yii2 update related model makes insert

Tags: activerecord, yii2

Depending on this question: [Yii2 updating two related models does not show data of the second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839910/yii2-updating-two-related-models-does-not-show-data-of-the-second). I have manged calling the related model `InvoiceItems` to the `Invoices` model it hasMany relation.

However, updating leads to insert new records in `invoice_items` table instead of updating the current related records to the `invoices` table.

I tried to add the `id` field of each `InvoiceItems` record in the `_form` view to solve this issue, but it still exist.

The following is `actionUpdate` of the `InvoicesController`:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        //$invoiceItems = new InvoiceItems();

        $count = count(Yii::$app->request->post('InvoiceItems', []));
        //Send at least one model to the form
        $invoiceItems = [new InvoiceItems()];

        //Create an array of the products submitted
        for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $invoiceItems[] = new InvoiceItems();
        }


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            //$invoiceItems->invoice_id = $model->id;
            if (Model::loadMultiple($invoiceItems, Yii::$app->request->post())){
              foreach ($invoiceItems as $item){
                $item->invoice_id = $model->id;
                //$item->id = $model->invoiceItems->id;
                $item->save(false);
              }

              return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            }
            else{
               return var_dump($invoiceItems);
            }
        } else {
          //$invoiceItems->invoice_id = $model->id;
          $invoiceItems = $this->findInvoiceItemsModel($model->id);
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
                'invoiceItems' => $invoiceItems,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

This is the code of `_form` view of `InvoicesController`:

```
<div class="invoices-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'created')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'type')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
  <hr />
  <?php if (is_array($invoiceItems)): ?>
  <?php foreach ($invoiceItems as $i => $item): ?>
  <?= $form->field($item, "[$i]id")->textInput();?>
    <?= $form->field($item, "[$i]item_id")->textInput();?>
    <?= $form->field($item, "[$i]unit_id")->textInput();?>
    <?= $form->field($item, "[$i]qty")->textInput();?>
  <?php  endforeach; ?>
  <?php  else: ?>
    <?= $form->field($invoiceItems, "item_id")->textInput();?>
    <?= $form->field($invoiceItems, "unit_id")->textInput();?>
    <?= $form->field($invoiceItems, "qty")->textInput();?>
  <?php endif; ?>    

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

The following screen shot, visually, demonstrates what I have got:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you in update you don't need new record you should remove

this part

```
    $count = count(Yii::$app->request->post('InvoiceItems', []));
    //Send at least one model to the form
    $invoiceItems = [new InvoiceItems()];

    //Create an array of the products submitted
    for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $invoiceItems[] = new InvoiceItems();
    }
```

The $invoiceItems you create in this way are obviuosly `"new"` and then are inserted ..for an update the model must to be not new..
You have already the related models to save they came from  post.. and from  load multiple

If you however need to manage new model (eg: because you added new record in wide form  update operation)  you can test

```
$yourModel->isNewRecord
```

and if this is new check then if the user have setted properly the related fields you can save it with

```
$yourModel->save();
```

otherwise you can simple discart.. (not saving it)

Comment: Please get a look at my answer, depending on yours.

Comment: I have update the asnwer with some suggestion for new records

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that this code below of course fills a array named $invoiceItems with the submitted data.

```
if (Model::loadMultiple($invoiceItems, Yii::$app->request->post())){
      foreach ($invoiceItems as $item){
        $item->invoice_id = $model->id;
        //$item->id = $model->invoiceItems->id;
        $item->save(false);
      }
}
```

But all $items have the scenario "insert" (could be that you allow the setting of the attribute 'ID' but normally this isn't allowed in the Gii generated code. and then you get "new items" whenever you save.

if you add a `return var_dump($invoiceItems);`after the loadMultiple you will see that only the `safe` attributes are filled with the submitted data.

You are also not validating them before saving, which is also kind of bad.

```
 if (Model::loadMultiple($invoiceItems, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($invoiceItems)) {
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html

Answer (score 0):

According to [scaisEdge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3522312/scaisedge) answer and [this widget documentation](https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform). I could able to determine the problem solution.

Simply, in my code I neglected the relation between the two models, when I say:

```
$count = count(Yii::$app->request->post('InvoiceItems', []));
        //Send at least one model to the form
        $invoiceItems = [new InvoiceItems()];
```

The value of `$invoiceItems` should be obtained using the relation like the following:

```
$invoiceItems = $model->invoiceItems;
```

However, I still have another issue with adding new records to the related model `InvoiceItems` during the update.

Comment: Adding new records Is a bit complex because the adding for an InvoceItems is requested in the view.. but in the view normally don't do action.. well you you may do so directly in view (not proper MVC oriented ) or you  may do by ajax calling a service action for getting the new  model you need..

Comment: I think the last mistake may help. i.e I just load predefined `InvoiceItems` for update, and then create new `InvoiceItems` model for the new records. It is a matter of how to creating the new insert fields in the view and how to load them in the controller.